# Can you pass array types to CIFilter kernels written in Metal?

Tags: ios, swift, metal, cifilter

The question says it all really. I'm trying to work out the correct way to declare an array of values (of type `float`) in the function declaration of a CIFilter written in Metal. However, none of the ways I've tried so far will function correctly, and I'm starting to wonder if it's possible. Most simply throw a bad access when I try to instantiate the kernel.

Example:

```
#include <metal_stdlib>
using namespace metal;
#include <CoreImage/CoreImage.h>

extern "C" { namespace coreimage {    
    float4 sampleCode(device float* array, destination dest) {
        /// Do Something here
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid Metal kernels don't support array parameters of arbitrary size. You either have to know the maximum capacity of the array during compile time (`float array[12]`, for instance), or you have to put your data into a buffer that you pass as sampler (texture) to the kernel.